# Populando Textbox em form diferente com dados de DataGridView

Tags: .net, vb.net

estou tentando adicionar os dados de uma linha de um DataGridView de uma form em outra ao clicar em um "botão de confirmação", mas pelas pesquisas que fiz em outros casos parecidos, o código está correto. Mesmo assim, não tenho retorno de código.

Estou fazendo o seguinte:

```
Form2.TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
```

Os dados devem aparecer na caixa de texto da outra form quando eu clico em um botão. O que há de errado? O retorno que tenho é "nada". Não dá nenhum erro, mas não funciona também.

Comment: -Lembrou de setar a propriedade "Modifiers" da TextBox para public? -Deu um form2.DataGridView1.Refresh()? Nota:
Lembrando que trocar valores entre forms dessa forma que você está fazendo é muito "dependente". É preciso "desacoplar" essa dependência. Eu crio uma propriedade pública no form2 e faço um handler que quando a propriedade muda lá no form2, já atualiza o que for preciso por lá.
Existem várias formas de fazer. Dá uma lida no livro "Use a cabeça - Padrões de Projetos". Lá tem vários problemas corriqueiros e como foram resolvidos.

Comment: Sugiro verificar duas coisas: 1. O valor já está armazenado na célula quando você executa esta linha? Talvez seja necessário chamar `DataGridView1.EndEdit` antes de executá-la. 2. Você está referindo a instância certa de `Form2`? Talvez seja necessário mudar para `My.Forms.Form2.Text = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Amigo tente verificar se o que você está pegando da DataGridView1 está retornando algo!

```
Dim teste = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
```

Com a variável teste você pode concluir que ou o erro está na DataGridView1 ou o erro está quando você está tentando passar o valor para a Text Box do Form2. Tente então passar o valor de teste para a Text Box do Form2

```
Form2.TextBox1.Text = teste
```

Espero que ajude ou minimize os problemas!